# In AngularJS how can I modify ng-click to fire on touchEnd on mobile?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Right now I'm detecting if the user's browser has touch events and listening for `touchend` instead of `click` on certain elements (to get over the 'wait-for-double-click' lag). It works great on a slide-out drawer I'm using.

I want to modify my app so that elements with `ng-click="function()"` will respond on `click` events for desktop (no touch events available) and respond on `touchend` for touch devices.

I'd rather not create a new directive for `ng-touch` or something and instead just modify the `ng-click` directive. I'm not sure how to modify a built-in Angular directive, though.

Is there a way to do this?

Here's a rough JS fiddle I started, but didn't get too far:

http://jsfiddle.net/MTh8U/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It actually sounds like you're trying to duplicate what Angular has already created for mobile:  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch.  Note that this is just another dependency you'll need to inject.